# Put space between end of page and button on iphone

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello guys i have trouble with my code. I have a bootstrap button and thats is fine but how can i put space between the button and end of the page. because its only on iphone the problem. Its very weird because when im holding in normal its good the button but when i turn my iphone there is no space anymore.

This is my button:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-center">
        <button type="button" class="learn btn btn-info">Learn more</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add some `padding` to the button or use `margin-bottom`

Answer (score 0):

As Ashiqur suggested, add some margin to the bottom of the button

```
.learn {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put CSS like this to your button :

```
button.learn {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    // Or :
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should add this :

```
 html,body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
```